# loop through datatable using column name but not exact column name

Tags: rpa, uipath

I am trying to get cell values of particular column having Column name which is not fixed after particular words.
i need to loop through Datatable and get values from column having column name as something like 'Value @02/29/2019'.
Here Date is changing but i want to know whether we can have something like contains or 'Values%'.

I tried regex but no luck.

expected is like:
- for each row (Test_DT)
- assign row("Value%") to CellValue
- end for

Comment: Couldn't you just access the cell by index?

Comment: i can't because index keeps on changing and also in future there might be additional columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can have something like contains to check the columns, try the following:

1. Create an excel application scope
2. use readrange to get data from excel inside a datatable.
3. use for each activity to loop through dt.rows
4. use for each acticity inside your first one to loop through dt.Columns
5. inside your foreach column use an if activity to check if col contains "Value @"

   col.ToString.contains("Value @")

[image]

Also you will have to change typearguments of your foreach activities otherwise you will get "Option String On Disallows Late Binding" error

[image]

Comment: @ShantanuKhaladkar I'm glad I could help.